# Opentracing tracing siblings

Tags: opentracing

I have a webserver which does some async processing by pushing data to a kafka consumer and returns a response. I want to be able to trace the webrequest + trace of the kafka consumer in a single trace. Is it possible to do it?

I tried to start the kafka consumer as the child of the first span but since the first span end when the api request ends, tracing tools show wrong times for trace. I know I'm doing it the wrong way.
Can someone please point me in the direction for implementing such a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `FOLLOWS_FROM` reference instead of a `CHILD_OF` reference for the span tracing in the Kafka consumer.

<sup>[Specification](https://github.com/opentracing/specification/blob/master/specification.md#references-between-spans)</sup>

Comment: I tried using follows from. Looks like google stacktrace does not support. Zipkin and jaegar are able to show it as 2 different services. But it does appear as a child to the web endpoint. Is this the expected behavior ?

Comment: Actually there seems to be no difference in how jaegar and zipkin treat childof and follows from.